# How to manage multiple AWS accounts from a single login

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have multiple AWS accounts and would like to know is there way in AWS portal or any other application where I can login and list all the account instances and other details in one place

Answer (score 0):

Login and go to this page, https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?ie=UTF8&action=access-key - the "Account Identifiers" at the bottom of the page may be of use to you.

Comment: No this is just the identifier for the account that you are logged in to. It doesn't display info across multiple accounts.